# Is my bottom bracket cracked?

Tags: road-bike, bottom-bracket, welding

I was inspecting my bike a couple of days ago and I found what seems like a crack on the bottom bracket welds (encircled below). I’ve ridden it for less than 150 kilometers. I know it’s hard to tell but I’d like to get the community’s opinion about it before getting it inspected by my local bike shop. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's hard to tell. Might just be a gouge in the paint. I don't think there's any way a bunch of Internet strangers could conclusively diagnose this based on a photo.

Comment: Better show that to a mechanic in person, not necessarily to a bike mechanic.

Comment: Some more pictures and camera angles would be good.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an obvious crack. What you can do to check is to:

1. Remove the cranks and bottom bracket.
2. In a dark place, shine a light from inside the bottom bracket shell and see if you can spot any light coming through the supposed "crack".

I'd be hesitant to bring it to the shop, if only because it's unlikely they will expend the labor to do it properly like this (there's no profit to be made).